# How to answer the inquiry: "Please confirm that you are not working for another company"

Tags: questions, negation

I got the following prompt.

> Please confirm that you are currently not working for another company in this field.

If I am not working for any other company, should I choose "Yes" or "No" as my response?

Comment: To be clear, you can reply "I am not."

Comment: Its a question im being asked and i only have 2 options YES or NO to select, its confusing me .

Comment: So the question should be "Are you currently working for another company", but not only were you asked a negative question, it is compounded by "Please confirm." If it is a paper form, ignore the options, and write "I am working for another company" or "I am not working..."

Comment: No its an online application form and i know that people are automatically kicked off for picking the wrong answer

Comment: Perhaps it is a sign that the whole future with this company will be blighted by poor management, confusion and uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you might be right. I am going to apply anyways have nothing to loose. What would you choose in my position if you had to ?

Comment: I would email them for clarification.

Comment: @Weather Vane Perhaps _that's_ the accepted response.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the enquirer hasn't been back since the day of posting, but in hindsight the thing to do would be to ask someone who was automatically kicked off: "If you were a liar, which response would you tell me to select?"

Comment: @Weather Vane How devious a liar?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've been turning that over in my mind too.

Comment: Same problem here, I've received a questionnaire from my son's school, and this question bugs me a lot:
**IF your child WILL NOT be returning for the 21.22 school year? It's a google form so I don't have place to write yes, he will return. or no, he won't.

Comment: Yes it's nuts. But looking at the first two words, "Please confirm," I'd answer Yes (for I confirm).

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly** suggest that you contact the company, because knowing how ELU recommends you interpret this does not ensure you answer it the way *they* intended. Someone who asks such an ambiguous/poorly phrased question may not have chosen the correct words. You could also ask for advice over at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

That caveat out of the way, I do have a suggestion.

Since it is not exactly a question as it stands, I found it helpful to rephrase it as one:
"Can you confirm that you are currently not working for another company in this field?"

If you are not currently working for another company in that field, the answer is *Yes*, because you *can* confirm it. More fully, the answer is "Yes, I can confirm that I am currently not working for another company in this field."

Alternatively, consider that the phrase *please confirm* indicates that the desired answer is *Yes*. It's an indication that the asker is checking something they assume to be true/require to be true to proceed.

Other examples:

- Please confirm that you wish to delete this document
- Please confirm that you do not wish to apply for any other positions
- Please confirm that you have a valid work visa or citizenship
- Please confirmed that you are not currently enrolled in school